# What does the below syntax where a bitwise NOT operator and Square brackets with colon used inside single quotes in Javascript indicate?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am new to Javascript, recently stumbled upon some javascript code which looks like this.

```
var axEnabled= '~[pref:axEnabled]~[prefnew:axEnabled]';
```

Same kind of syntax is used in HTML as well.

```
 ~[wp:nav_css]
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around what the syntax means. I am familiar with the bitwise not (~) operator. I am quite familiar with how objests and arrays work in Javascript.

I tried searching online for the syntax, seems like its rare/old. Hence, unable to find it anywhere.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's just a string. Who ever uses the content of `axEnabled` should know what to do with it.

Comment: What is pref here in [pref:axEnabled]? And why does the syntax use square brackets and colon? In case of a normal string variable, we can use `var axEnabled = axEnabled? axEnabled: '';`

Comment: _"What is pref here in [pref:axEnabled]?"_ - That's a question for who-ever uses that string. _"And why does the syntax use square brackets and colon?"_ - That's a question for who-ever uses that string. _"In case of a normal string variable..."_ - That's a "normal" string variable. `var axEnabled = "bla blubb"`. The actual content of the string has nothing to do with how JavaScript works.

Comment: _"I am new to Javascript..."_ - Stay away from `var` and use `let`/`const` instead.